# Proof of Ceva theorem using Barycentric coordinates

Tags: proof-explanation, barycentric-coordinates

There is a good proof in this article: http://zacharyabel.com/papers/Barycentric_A07.pdf (at the end of the first page). I can't really understand it. How does he find this $P$, how does he find out that $r_c$ must be equal to $1/r_ar_b$ .

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I suggest that you add the `proof-explanation` tag to your question.

Comment: Thanks! I just did :)